# cordova video compression plugin

Tags: cordova, video-processing

I have a cordova application. In which user can upload a media file from a storage. That data is uploaded to the server via an ajax post.

**Problem:**

When uploading the file, if the file size is large(Ex: video files) it takes a lot of time to upload. So need to compress the file before posting.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried below plugins but video compression didn't work.

https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor

So is there any way to compress the video using cordova plugin?

Comment: hello, Have you finally found something? a greeting